# where error ？kvs = {k:v.strip("'") for k,v in re.findall(r"\('(\S+)', ('.*?')\)", line)}

Tags: python, key

```
kvs = {k:v.strip("'") for k,v in re.findall(r"\('(\S+)', ('.*?')\)", line)}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./scanl2logs.py", line 24, in <module>
    from l2historybuffer import L2HistoryBuffer
  File "/opt/jiaping_python_syslog/ScanSwitchesLogFiles-master/l2historybuffer.py", line 69
    kvs = {k:v.strip("'") for k,v in re.findall(r"\('(\S+)', ('.*?')\)", line)}
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `strip( ' )`, where's the other `'`?

Comment: Note that the error for the *posted* code is `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character` pointing to the end of the line.

Comment: Your traceback shows different code from what you posted: `kvs = {k:v.strip("'") for k,v in re.findall(r"\('(\S+)', ('.*?')\)", line)}`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: The OP doesn't seem to know how to copy and paste properly..

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using a version of python before Python 2.7. [Dictionary comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#python-3-1-features) were not added until 2.7.

You will have to do something like:

```
dict((k,v.strip(' ')) for k,v in re.findall(r'\('(\S+)', ('.*?')\)' , line))
```

Or upgrade your python version :).

Comment: Take a good look at the exception message, the traceback shows the **correct** code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So it does ;)